# Connection hangs with Fugu cannot connect

Tags: password, ssh

I've seen Fugu questions asked on this site, but I haven't found an answer for this:

My sysadmin locked my account on the server side, due to unexpected activity from my account. My password is now reset, and I can log in to the remote server via ssh in Terminal.

When I try to log in to the same remote machine via Fugu, the connection hangs and after a few minutes, Fugu gives up trying. I never saved a password with Fugu - I enter it each time I connect.

Could the login problem be related to the password change? If not, what else could be the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround more than answer:

I needed Fugu to copy files from the remote machine to my local machine. I can do that without Fugu using this:

`scp username@remote_host:filename.ext path/to/local/dir`